# Loading language corpus in GATE

Tags: nlp

I am new to gate. I want to create a corpus from documents. I have large number of documents so that it is difficult to load them each time and create the corpus manually.Are there any easy way of directly creating corpus?

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Used to hold the data store saved the records for processing
 */
private static DataStore ProcessingDataStore = null;

/**
 * Holds the corpus for processing
 */
private static Corpus ProcessingCorpus = null;


private static void LoadSerialDataStore(String dataStoreDirPath)
        throws Exception {
    File dataStoreDirFile = new File(dataStoreDirPath);
    if (!dataStoreDirFile.exists()) {
        if (!dataStoreDirFile.mkdirs()) {
            logger.log(Level.WARNING,
                    "Data store directory creation false!");
            return;
        }
        ProcessingDataStore = (SerialDataStore) Factory.createDataStore(
                SerialDataStore.class.getName(), dataStoreDirFile.toURI()
                        .toString());
        ProcessingDataStore.open();
        ProcessingCorpus = (Corpus) ProcessingDataStore.adopt(Factory
                .newCorpus(""), null);
        ProcessingDataStore.sync(ProcessingCorpus);
    } else {
        ProcessingDataStore = (SerialDataStore) Factory.openDataStore(
                SerialDataStore.class.getName(), dataStoreDirFile.toURI()
                        .toString());
        ProcessingDataStore.open();
        ProcessingCorpus = CorpusUtil.loadSerialCorpus(ProcessingDataStore);
    }
}

private static void CreateSerialDataStore(String dataStoreDirPath){
      LoadSerialDataStore(dataStoreDirPath);
      Document tempDocument = Factory.newDocument(content);
      FeatureMap featureMap = Factory.newFeatureMap();
      tempDocument.setFeatures(featureMap);
      ProcessingCorpus.add(tempDocument);
      ProcessingCorpus.unloadDocument(tempDocument);
      Factory.deleteResource(tempDocument);
}
```